# Oracle Database SQL query to split data of column into multiple columns and multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Imagine i have table with below structure,

```
ID        Value                      Timestamp
1    {A,B,C,D}{E,F,G,H}{I,J,K,L}     12-12-2022
```

Now want fetch data from above table and store into different table with below structure,

```
ID    Value1   Value2     Value3    Value4   Tiemstamp
1       A        B           C        D      12-12-2022
1       E        F           G        H      12-12-2022
1       I        J           K        L      12-12-2022
```

Comment: Is it really Oracle 11g ? If not, what is your db version ?

Comment: Dou you have always 4 values in the each object?

Comment: Such content violates the first normalisation rule if being dealt with using database features.
Please either treat it as a TLOB, BLOB or even VARCHAR and do the inner fiddling within application code, or (better) if you really want to work with this content using database features, store it in a normalized way: [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 2):

One of the possibilities is to use string functions combined with xmltable:

```
  with t(ID, Value, tstamp) as (
    select 1, '{A,B,C,D}{E,F,G,H}{I,J,K,L}',      date '2022-12-12' from dual union all
    select 5, '{PQR,ZXY,C,A7}{P,Q,R,S}{D,C,B,A}', date '2023-02-17' from dual)

  select id, tstamp, 
         substr(cv, 1, instr(cv,',') - 1) va,
         substr(cv, instr(cv,',', 1, 1)+1, instr(cv,',', 1, 2) - instr(cv,',',1, 1)-1) vb,
         substr(cv, instr(cv,',', 1, 2)+1, instr(cv,',', 1, 3) - instr(cv,',',1, 2)-1) vc,
         substr(cv, instr(cv,',', 1, 3)+1) vd
  from (select id, tstamp, trim(column_value) cv
        from t, xmltable(ltrim(replace(replace(value, '{', ',"'), '}', '"'), ',')) xt);
```

Output:

```
    ID TSTAMP      VA     VB     VC     VD
 ----- ----------- ------ ------ ------ -------
     1 2022-12-12  A      B      C      D
     1 2022-12-12  E      F      G      H
     1 2022-12-12  I      J      K      L
     5 2023-02-17  PQR    ZXY    C      A7
     5 2023-02-17  P      Q      R      S
     5 2023-02-17  D      C      B      A
```

Comment: I cannot hard code that part of {A, B, C, D} because it will have multiple row of array in single column

Comment: I am not hardcoding it. The `with` clause contains sample data. You can see query working on table in [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kQ0iEDza). If this is not OK please edit your question and show different examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query and simple string functions:

```sql
WITH bounds (id, value, timestamp, spos, c1pos, c2pos, c3pos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         timestamp,
         1,
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 2),
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 3),
         INSTR(value, '}', 1, 1)
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  INSTR(value, '}', 1, 1) > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         timestamp,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(value, ',', epos + 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, ',', epos + 1, 2),
         INSTR(value, ',', epos + 1, 3),
         INSTR(value, '}', epos + 1, 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  INSTR(value, '}', epos + 1, 1) > 0
)
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(value, spos + 1, c1pos - spos - 1) AS value1,
       SUBSTR(value, c1pos + 1, c2pos - c1pos - 1) AS value2,
       SUBSTR(value, c2pos + 1, c3pos - c2pos - 1) AS value3,
       SUBSTR(value, c3pos + 1, epos - c3pos - 1) AS value4,
       timestamp
FROM   bounds;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Value, Timestamp) AS
SELECT 1, '{A,B,C,D}{E,F,G,H}{I,J,K,L}', DATE '2022-12-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '{XYZ,ABC,DEF,PQR}{12345,,34,9876}', SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 | VALUE4 | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | 2022-12-12 00:00:00 |
| 2 | XYZ | ABC | DEF | PQR | 2023-04-06 21:26:15 |
| 1 | E | F | G | H | 2022-12-12 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 12345 | *null* | 34 | 9876 | 2023-04-06 21:26:15 |
| 1 | I | J | K | L | 2022-12-12 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DOrKPjR5)